# Java generics code cannot compile

Tags: java

I have the following code that give me trouble compiling.

Give me this error

```
Error:(20, 22) java: incompatible types: com.company.Main.Impl cannot be converted to T
```

I only need that interface to work in this function, and I don't want to change the function body much.

Why doesn't this work?
and
How could I make this work?

```
    package com.company;

public class Main {

    class Impl implements someinterface, anotherinterface{

        @Override
        public Integer getInteger() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    class BigObject{
        public Impl get(){
            return new Impl();
        }
    }

    private <T extends someinterface & anotherinterface> Integer myfunc(BigObject bg){

        T xy = bg.get(); // this line will not compile????
        if (xy.isOK()) // from someinterface 
           return xy.getInteger(); // from anotherinterface
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need the generic parameter in the first place? From the looks of it, `someinterface` (which should be written in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)), contains only the method `getInteger()`. You can replace `T` with `someinterface`

Comment: `T` is *something* that implements `someinterface`; it's not necessarily an `Impl`. Just use `someinterface xy = ...` instead.

Comment: Generics here are nonsensical.  Remove the generic declaration and replace `T xy = bg.get();` with `someinterface xy = bg.get();` then debug.

Comment: @AndyTurner see the updated user case with less trivial example.

Comment: @user40129 exactly the same comment. `T` is *something* that implements `someinterface` and also `anotherinterface`; it's not necessarily `Impl`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, correct, but this function doesn't require it to be impl, just need anything that implement those interfaces. isn't that what generics are for?

Comment: @user40129 Then create a `newinterface extends someinterface, anotherinterface` and replace `T` with `newinterface`.

Comment: Generics are invariant. [Related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjDLw.png).

Comment: @Turing85, then I have to go to change My Impl implementation to implement newinterface, don't really want to change that code. Thinking this is a giant code base. and you want to be less invasive.

Comment: @user40129 ... then replace `T` with `Impl`. `BigObject` does not seem to inherit from anything, so it seems pretty fix to me. Otherwise, you would need to somehow make `BigObject` generic in `get()`'s return type.

Comment: You can always cast `T xy = (T) bg.get();` if you don't want to change other parts of your code.

Comment: @Pshemo: this is brilliant. however I do want it to give me error if bg.get() doesn't give me the right interface.

Comment: @user40129 If you do the cast, you really do not need any generics. `someinterface si = bg.get(); anotherinterface ai = (anotherinterface) si;`. You know... generics are nothing else than compile-time type assertion, which you totally forego with casts.

Comment: @Turing85: right. I do like the type checking to give me error if what returned doesn't give the correct interface. so I need two temporary objects one for each interface before I can call that. This seems like a lack of feature on java side.

Comment: @user40129 Again the question: why do you need generics? Why not replace `T` with `Impl`?

Answer (score 2):

It won't compile because in Java, generics are **invariant**, [see related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

With the following line of code:

```
<T extends SomeInterface> Integer myfunc(BigObject bg) { ... }
```

you are saying that `T` is something that is *some* kind of `SomeInterface`, or, more precisely, a certain type that is a subtype of `SomeInterface`. The compiler complains about `T xy = bg.get()`, because `bg.get()` returns a certain subtype of `T`, but that type may or may not be the same as `Impl`.

As an analogy, you are saying something like this:

```
class Cat extends Animal { }
class AnimalObj {
    public Cat get() {
        return new Cat();
    }
}

private <T extends Animal> Integer myfunc(AnimalObj bg) {
    T xy = bg.get();
    ...
}
```

`T` could be a `Cat`, but it could also be a `Dog`. Who knows. So that's why the compiler complains.

If you don't care about the subtype, **you should drop generics**, and write this instead:

```
private Integer myfunc(AnimalObj bg) {
    Animal xy = bg.get();
    ...
}
```

Since `myFunc` accepts a `BigObject`, which is able to deliver a concrete `Impl`, you could just replace `<T extends someinterface & anotherinterface>` by `Impl`.

---

#### Read more

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745301#2745301)
- [Generics – The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: Yes it can also be a Dog, does it matter. `myfunc` cares only about any type of `Animal`. Right?

Comment: No, not quite. Not "any type of `Animal`" (then we could just write `Animal xy = ...`) but merely "a specific, but unknown type which is a subclass of `Animal`". They are not the same.

Comment: Right, but the compiler should complain if bg.get() doesn't have those interfaces,  why does the compiler wants to check more than that?

Comment: @user40129 According to that logic, `Dog d = new Cat()` would be possible, if they both implement `Strokeable`. The fact that two classes implement the same interfaces, doesn't mean they are interchangeable.

Comment: @MCEmperor, If <T extends strokable&willpee>, T d canott be a new Cat()?

Comment: @user40129 Indeed, because `T` *might* be a `Dog`. Both `Dog` and `Cat` implement `Strokable` and `WillPee`, but they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: from my function I don't care about Dog cannot be Cat, I just need d.willpee() to return boolean. if I somehow calls d.bark(),  d.bark() (and only d.bark()) should cause compilation error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163079/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-user40129).

Answer (score 0):

Lets change the `myfunc` a little bit so that it will return the generic type `T`:

```
private static <T extends someinterface & anotherinterface> T myfunc(BigObject bg){
    return bg.get();
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
Impl i1 = myfunc( new BigObject() );
```

and like this:

```
Impl2 i2 = myfunc( new BigObject() );
```

But if `BigObject.get` would have only returned `Impl` you would have error with second call that expected `Impl2`.

Comment: this doesn't compile. and gives an error at bg.get()

Comment: Yes it does not because `bg.get()` is only returning `Impl`. The example I gave shows that with signature `myfunc` has, `bg.get()` function cannot just return `Impl`. The compiler cannot make sure that the caller of `myfunc` wont specify `Impl2` for T.

Comment: a reasonable compiler will let you compile the function but neither of the function calls. Because it doesn't know if that generic type returned can be translated to Impl/Impl2, but if il is of type <T extends someinterface&anotherinterface> (instead of Impl/Impl2),  function calls should compile, since there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, that is why as others suggested you need to change `bg.get()` to be `public <T extends someinterface & anotherinterface> T get()`. This way compiler can be sure that `bg.get()` will handle `Impl` and `Impl2`.

Comment: don't think that's what they suggests, because public <T extends someinterface & anotherinterface> T get() on BigObject will not compile.

Comment: You also need to cast unfortunately: `return (T)( new Impl() );`

Comment: yeah... seems unavoidable, but compiler has all the information to make a decision, I really shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: With cast you telling compiler that: "Trust me I will never call `bg.get()` and expect `Impl2`. If I do I am ok with `ClassCastException`."